# Add Calender View with multiple dates selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar, tapku

I want to add Calendar View to the app,i have tried Tapku and kal but both of them does not provide multiple Dates selection, is there any that can provide multiple date selection calendar view like user can select many dates as he wants from the calendar.

Comment: [try one of this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar)

Comment: @FahimParkar is there anyone who provivde multiple date selection not the range of date

Comment: did you checked all of this? itna to karde yaar...

Comment: @ShehbazKhan Did U find any Solution ?

Comment: yeah i did custom thing on tapku calendar

Comment: @ShehbazKhan can u please guide me how to do that.

Comment: I need some thing like this design, https://www.dropbox.com/s/si7dz8rzxjzyzy6/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-26%20at%2012.41.58%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Let me know which one is the better option for me

Comment: you can go with tapku like u will be able to do multi selection easily but not sure about the exact design u send

Comment: How You maintain In color for dates when u selecting multiple dates in Tapku

Comment: Hey  Could U please guide me how to integrate Tapku in project I'm getting lots of errors like curry frame work etc. Please guide with some steps